# triple DES result length

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric

If I encrypt emails so that I can store them in a database, the resulting string is longer than the email itself.  Is there a maximum length to this resulting coded string?  if so, does it depend on both key length and the email length?  I need to know this so I can set my database fields to the correct length.
Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the *padding scheme* you use, E.g. PKCS7 will add bytes such that the output is the input size padded to the next multiple of the block size.

Comment: It also depends on how you encode it. Furthermore, you probably need to store the IV and possibly an authentication tag. But Rob already put that in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex K. notes, for block ciphers (like DES), common modes will pad them out to a multiple of the block size. The block size for 3DES is 64-bits (8 bytes). The most common padding scheme is PKCS7, which pads the block with "n x n bytes." This is to say, if you need one bytes of padding, it pads with 0x01. If you need four bytes of padding, it pads with 0x04040404 (4x 4s). If your data is already the right length, it pads with a full block (8 bytes of 0x08 for 3DES).

The short version is that the padded cipher text for 3DES can be up to 8 bytes longer than the plaintext. If your encryption scheme is a typical, insecure implementation, this is the length. The fact that you're using 3DES (an obsolete cipher) makes it a bit more likely that it's also insecurely implemented, and so this is the answer.

But if your scheme is implemented well, then there could be quite a few other things attached to the message. There could be 8 bytes of initialization vector. There could be a salt of arbitrary length if you're using a password. There could be an HMAC. There could be lots of things that could add an arbitrary amount of space. (The [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md) format, for example, adds up to 82 bytes to the message.) So you need to know how your format is implemented.

Comment: Also don't forget that your hopefully encrypting the message as unicode so your passing a clear text buffer double the size of the apparent email length

Comment: I don't understand why that would be true. RFC 5322 (and 2822 and 822) email messages are US-ASCII. But in any case, you should encrypt what you have. There's no particular reason here to re-encode messages in UTF-16 (Unicode hasn't fit in 16 bits since the 90s).

Comment: Actually, most modes do not use padding at all. It's just that ECB and CBC mode are still used a lot (and probably too much).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes agreed. "Many" is misleading here. The right word is "common." Fixed.